# How can my ng-repeat not work on this small code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So currently I am following the course 'shaping up with angular.js', I quite like it so far but I am only on 1.5 'Built in Directives'. But I can't get my head around the ng-repeat what they using in the course.

So what you need to to do is just put ng-repeat on the div and it should loop through all items in the array and show them. Maby I mistyped something but I rewrote the thing 2 times and read it over like a 100 times.. :(

This is my current html template

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="store">
<body ng-controller="storeController as store">
    <div ng-hide="store.product.soldOut" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
        <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>

        <h2>${{store.product.price}}</h2>

        <p>{{store.product.description}}</p>

        <button ng-show="store.product.canPurchase"> Add to cart </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my app.js file.

```
(function () {
     var app = angular.module('store', []);

        app.controller('storeController', function () {
        this.products = gems;
     });

    var gems = [
        {
            name: 'Dodecahedron',
            price: 295,
            description: 'Nice gem',
            canPurchase: true,
            soldOut: false
        },
        {
            name: "Pentagonal Gem",
            price: 5.95,
            description: "more nice gems",
            canPurchase: true,
            soldOut: false
        }
    ]
})();
```

I can't seems to find out why it isn't repeating itself. And I dont even know why in the course they say 'product in store.products' there is no 'product' called anywhere.

I put it in a codepen also
http://codepen.io/denniswegereef/pen/JYwora

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the "store" from your inline bindings. The moment you use `ng-repeat` you reference your data object from the `in` clause like this:

```
<div ng-hide="product.soldOut" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
    <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
    <h2>${{product.price}}</h2>
    <p>{{product.description}}</p>
    <button ng-show="product.canPurchase"> Add to cart </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh man, I didn't see that one coming. Works perfect now I can continu with my course Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is messy. Here is the correct version

```js
var app = angular.module('store', []);

app.controller('storeController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.products = [
        {
            name: 'Dodecahedron',
            price: 295,
            description: 'Nice gem',
            canPurchase: true,
            soldOut: false
        },
        {
            name: "Pentagonal Gem",
            price: 5.95,
            description: "more nice gems",
            canPurchase: true,
            soldOut: false
        }
    ];
});
```

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app="store">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="storeController">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
      <div ng-hide="product.soldOut">
        <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>

        <h2>${{product.price}}</h2>

        <p>{{product.description}}</p>

        <button ng-show="product.canPurchase"> Add to cart </button>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know the code is messy and not total right, I just follow the course from the start they didn't use the scope yet. but thanksfor changing it corrent :)

Comment: You do not need to use the scope when you use `controller as name` for the controller directive. In a productive environment you would store your data however in a factory object, or retrieve it from a service and not have it in a variable outside angular but for an example of ng-repeat it is irrelevant.